# How can i change the border of <fieldset> in Bootstrap 4.2?

Tags: html, css

Briefly, i want to change the color of an outline of a fieldset to a color of my choice (blue for example) instead of the default grey outline color.

And this happens when i click on the (input) field:

**Note** CSS property does not work

I use this code

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="legned.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-vus3nQHTD+5mpDiZ4rkEPlnkcyTP+49BhJ4wJeJunw06ZAp+wzzeBPUXr42fi8If" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a9xOd0rz8w0J8zqj1qJic7GPFfyMfoiuDjC9rqXlVOcGO/dmRqzMn34gZYDTel8k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Bootstrap Legned</title>
</head>

<body>

  <fieldset class="border p-2 w-25 mr-auto ml-2">
    <legend class="w-auto">First Name</legend>
    <input name="text1" type="text" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="border p-2 w-25 mr-auto ml-2">
    <legend class="w-auto">Last Name</legend>
    <input name="text1" type="text" />
  </fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```

The illustrations are attached below:

[Before click on input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVQVO.png)

[After click on input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fepir.png)

Comment: You need to use a selector with greater [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the one Bootstrap is using to style the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix how you're importing your `Bootstrap` as well, but when I removed `.border`, your CSS worked after adding `!important` to make sure it overrides the inherited `Bootstrap` CSS.

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

  <fieldset class="p-2 w-25 mr-auto ml-2">
    <legend class="w-auto">First Name</legend>
    <input name="text1" type="text" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="p-2 w-25 mr-auto ml-2">
    <legend class="w-auto">Last Name</legend>
    <input name="text1" type="text" />
  </fieldset>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm 
Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty `div` to the `fieldset` and style it this way:

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

input:focus ~ div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

fieldset > div {
  height: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="legned.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-vus3nQHTD+5mpDiZ4rkEPlnkcyTP+49BhJ4wJeJunw06ZAp+wzzeBPUXr42fi8If" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a9xOd0rz8w0J8zqj1qJic7GPFfyMfoiuDjC9rqXlVOcGO/dmRqzMn34gZYDTel8k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Bootstrap Legned</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset class="p-2 w-25 mr-auto ml-2">
    <legend class="w-auto">First Name</legend>
    <input name="text1" type="text" />
    <div></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="p-2 w-25 mr-auto ml-2">
    <legend class="w-auto">Last Name</legend>
    <input name="text1" type="text" />
    <div></div>
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```